# Package not populated for selected apk in appium

Tags: android, windows, selenium, automation, appium

I am new to Android Automation. I have installed Appium 1.3.7.2 on my windows machine. I have also set `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` paths properly. But when I am selecting APK for any android app in `Appium.exe`, its packages are not getting populated there. Because of this I am unable to do further operations and have been stuck since long time. Is there any setting for this to work? If not, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: plz share ur code whatever you have done so far

Comment: @gaurav: I havent written any code yet. I am at very beginner level right from starting the appium server.

Comment: ask package name to your developer and put it in setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aapt command in the Android SDK to get the list of packages and activities in a apk file.

```
aapt dump xmltree <apk-file-path> AndroidManifest.xml
```

This will output the AndroidManifest.xml file in a readable format and you can locate the activity names and package names for the apk.

aapt tool can be found in the `<sdk_directory>/build-tools/<version_number>/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I understood the issue now. It was due to the blank spaces in apk file name & folder name. I removed the spaces & now its working fine for me.